# How can I reset an MySQL AutoIncrement using a MAX value from another table?

Tags: sql, mysql, auto-increment, reset

I know this won't work. I tried it in various forms and failed all times. What is the simplest way to achieve the following result?

```
ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT = (select max(ID) from ABC);
```

This is great for automation projects.

```
SELECT @max := (max(ID)+1) from ABC;        -> This works!
select ID from ABC where ID = (@max-1);     -> This works!
ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT = (@max+1);  -> This fails :( Why?
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
  SELECT @max := MAX(ID)+ 1 FROM ABC;

  PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE ABC AUTO_INCREMENT = ?';
  EXECUTE stmt USING @max;

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Sounds like a pretty solid answer for my question! Thank you!

Comment: `PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT = ?'`
 generate error for me :(

Comment: The error is just `You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near '?' at line 1`. You can see it in [this fiddle](http://rextester.com/PPLB35064). It seems that the `?` is not accepted in the PREPARE statement with `AUTO_INCREMENT`. The [Anurag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17617206/1677209) answer has a workaround for it.

Comment: @T30 I got the same error with '?', I have posted a workaround for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41466825/2822296)

Comment: In the answer, the same table ABC is used for both getting MAX(ID) and in the prepared statement to alter table. This causes effectively no change. @ThinkCode wanted to set auto_increment of another table.

Comment: I use MySQL 8 and received the same error as @T30. Using Saeed's answer it worked.

Comment: @ChetanKhilosiya You are not correct. Deleting from the table will cause gaps in IDs and if you delete from the end of the table MAX(ID) can be much lower than the AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 33):

Following [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), this worked for me in MySQL 5.7:

```
SET @m = (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM ABC);
SET @s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT=', @m);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: Might need `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1 FROM ABC` if ABC is an empty table.

Answer (score 11):

Whoever is having a problem with **PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT = ?'** can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reset_xyz_autoincrement
BEGIN
      SELECT @max := MAX(ID)+ 1 FROM ABC;
      set @alter_statement = concat('ALTER TABLE temp_job_version AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @max);
      PREPARE stmt FROM @alter_statement;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: I had high hopes for this one, but I get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
      SELECT @max := MAX(id)+ 1 FROM test' at line 2

Comment: It is missing brackets on the first line. Make it "CREATE PROCEDURE reset_xyz_autoincrement ()"

Answer (score 9):

I'm creating an automated database transformation script for a new version of my application.

In one table, I needed to change the primary auto-increment field to a different field. Since this page came up first many times while I googled a solution for it, here's a solution that eventually worked for me:

```
-- Build a new ID field from entry_id, make it primary and fix the auto_increment for it:
ALTER TABLE  `entries` ADD  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL FIRST;
UPDATE entries SET id = entry_id;
ALTER TABLE  `entries` ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` );

-- ...the tricky part of it:
select @ai := (select max(entry_id)+1 from entries);
set @qry = concat('alter table entries auto_increment=',@ai);
prepare stmt from @qry; execute stmt;

-- ...And now it's possible to switch on the auto_increment:
ALTER TABLE  `entries` CHANGE  `id`  `id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 6):

Reset Auto Increment IDs.

*[Reset Auto Increment IDs](http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/3042-reset-auto-increment-ids)*

Update all auto increment columns in a database to the smallest possible value based on current values in the databases. We needed to do this after cleaning out a database.

Use a *[prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)* within a [stored procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure):

```
drop PROCEDURE if exists reset_autoincrement;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE reset_autoincrement (IN schemaName varchar(255))
 BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE o_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE o_table VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE extra LIKE '%auto_increment%' and table_schema=schemaName;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
     FETCH cur1 INTO o_name, o_table;

     IF done THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
     END IF;

  set @qry1 = concat('SELECT MAX(`',o_name,'`) + 1 as autoincrement FROM `',o_table,'` INTO @ai');
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @qry1;
  EXECUTE stmt1;

  IF @ai IS NOT NULL THEN
      SELECT  o_name, o_table;
   select @qry1;
   select @ai;
   set @qry2 = concat('ALTER TABLE `',o_table,'` AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @ai);
   select @qry2;
   PREPARE stmt2 FROM @qry2;
   EXECUTE stmt2;
  END IF;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
 END //
DELIMITER ;


call reset_autoincrement('my_schema_name');
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd probably use either a shell script or a little C#/C++ application or PHP/Ruby/Perl script to do this in 2 queries:

- Grab the value you want `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ABC;`
- Alter the table using the value `ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT = <insert value retrieved from first query here>`

Obviously being careful that the new auto increment won't cause any key clashes with existing data in the `XYZ` table.

Comment: I thought it can easily be done by using only MySQL queries. Looks like I am out of luck. Any other solution using only MySQL - using variables in MySQL? 

I want to execute a bunch of queries in one .sql file rather than shell scripts and Perl/Python scripts.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys. I have come up with a not so intuitive solution. The best part is that it works!

```
SELECT @max := max(ID) from ABC;       
ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE XYZ ADD column ID INTEGER primary key auto_increment;
UPDATE XYZ SET ContactID = (ContactID + @max);
```

Comment: Where does ContactID comes from?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this in MySQL alone, you can just dump the dynamically built alter command to a file on disk and then execute it.

Like so:

```
select concat('ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT = ',max(ID)+1,';') as alter_stmt
into outfile '/tmp/alter_xyz_auto_increment.sql'
from ABC;

\. /tmp/alter_xyz_auto_increment.sql
```