# MySQL does not accept this procedure. Can you help, please?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reset_xyz_autoincrement
BEGIN

  SELECT @max := MAX(ID)+ 1 FROM ABC; 

  PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE XYZ AUTO_INCREMENT = ?'
  EXECUTE stmt USING @max 

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
```

I took the code from here:
[How to Reset an MySQL AutoIncrement using a MAX value from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410689/how-to-reset-an-mysql-autoincrement-using-a-max-value-from-another-table)

This is the MySQL output:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN

  SELECT @max := MAX(ID)+ 1 FROM ABC' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     CREATE PROCEDURE reset_xyz_autoincrement
          (username varchar(64),password varchar(64))     // here you use your columns
      BEGIN
```

EDIT:

try this

```
     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS reset_xyz_autoincrement;
     CREATE PROCEDURE reset_xyz_autoincrement (userid INT)
      BEGIN
```

Comment: Still no luck. I get error near '' on line 3

`SELECT @curID := MAX(movies.id) FROM movies;`

Comment: now the error is not near of the begin , so it fixed the first error , then error now is in SELECT

Comment: The query runs normally when not in the procedure. I mean it outputs the correct thing but in the procedure it fails...

Comment: make sure that `reset_xyz_autoincrement` and `ABC` and `XYZ` in your real table are three diffrents tables

Answer (score 1):

You should do follow:

1. Use function brace
2. Use semicolon every statement.

> delimiter $$
>   CREATE PROCEDURE reset_xyz_autoincrement()
>           BEGIN
>
> ```
>       SELECT @max:=MAX(ID)+ 1 FROM Company_Master; 
>
>       PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE Dept_Master AUTO_INCREMENT = ?';
>       EXECUTE stmt USING @max ;
>
>       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
>
>     END$$
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `delimiter $$` before the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

EDIT:

I lost track in the comments on what is the current version of your procedure, but there is an error on your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT @yourVar := MAX(ID)+ 1 FROM ABC;
```

should become

```
SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 INTO @yourVar FROM ABC;
```

Plus, I think you should `DECLARE myVar INT` (assuming it's an Integer) before, and please notice that `max` is also a MySQL keyword, so I would avoid using that name in my procedure.

Comment: I tried it even before posting but still no luck. I get and error again:
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN SELECT @max := MAX(id)+ 1 FROM movies; PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABL' at line 2`

I also tried it with `delimiter ;` no luck too...